# If a person tells he will commit a sin and then repent intentionally but then regret his sin, will he be forgiven?

Tags: sin, tawba

If a person commits a sin intentionally and then tells he will ask for forgiveness , but then regrets the sin, will he be forgiven?

Comment: Your question title and content look contradictory to me the title indicates doing something sinful while the content says you want to repent. Again please avoid long question titles in other words the question title should indicate what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (pbuh) said:

> “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah
> (followers) for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not
> act upon it or speak of it.” 
> **-Al-Bukhari, Muslim.**

Be warned that sinning can cause one to go astray:

> “And We shall turn their hearts and their eyes away (from guidance),
> as they refused to believe therein for the first time, and We shall
> leave them in their trespass to wander blindly.”
>
>  **-Qur'an 6:110**

However, if you still plan to indulge in the sin intentionally, Allah has enjoined repentance upon His slaves. He says:

> “O you who believe! Turn to Allah with sincere repentance! It may be
> that your Lord will remit from you your sins, and admit you into
> Gardens under which rivers flow (Paradise).”
>
>  **-Qur'an 66:8**

Allah has told us that He accepts repentance from His slaves and that He will pardon them; indeed He will turn their bad deeds into good deeds. Allah says:

> “And it is He Who accepts repentance from His slaves, and forgives
> sins, and He knows what you do.”
>
>  **-Qur'an 42:25**

> “Except those who repent and believe (in Islamic Monotheism), and do
> righteous deeds; for those, Allah will change their sins into good
> deeds, and Allah is Oft‑Forgiving, Most Merciful.” 
>  **-Qur'an 25:70**

The thing is, as Muslims, just like all of mankind, we have free will. Allah says do whatever you please. Sin, disobey Me but be warned: sinning causes the heart to blacken. Satan will cause corruption and convince you that Allah will never forgive you, which will result in you never repenting and die as a sinner.

Of course, you may be lucky and repent before it's too late but it's a risky thing to do.

Allah tells us to stay away from sin, it's an evil way. But since we are humans, we are prone to sinning which is why Allah has a lot of mercy upon repentance.
However, when repenting, you must follow this criterion:

- Sincerity in repentance
- (Giving up the sin
- Regretting the sin
- Resolving not to go back to the sin
- Repenting in time, for Allah, does not accept repentance when the
  death rattle sounds before the soul is taken, or after the sun rises
  from its place of setting
- Restoring people’s rights if the sin had to do with the rights of
  other people